# limit of a hyperbolic function

Tags: limits, hyperbolic-functions

How to evaluate this limit without using hopital rule:
$$\lim_{c\rightarrow + \infty}{\frac{\text{sinh}\sqrt{c}}{2\sqrt{x}}}$$

Here is what I have done so far:

- we know that $\text{sinh}(x)= \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}.$

So applying this to the limit we find :
$$L= \lim_{c\rightarrow +\infty}{\frac{e^{\sqrt{c}}}{2\sqrt{c}}}.$$
(the other part tends to zero.)
So first is my approach right+would this lead me into anything?)
And second how should I complete(any hints?)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it Sinh[Sqrt[c]] or Sinh[Sqrt[x]] ?

Comment: Sinh[sqrt[c]] butthe point I discussed in the middle is a general one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the e-function increases faster than any power function, the limit is $\infty$.

Comment: To see this easier, replace $\sqrt{c}$ by d. If c tends to infinity, also d does.

Comment: Can`t we prove it by calculation

Comment: Use the taylor series of exp(x) to see that it grows faster than any power function. Perhaps, L'hospital can be used, but I am not sure it works for nonexisting limits.